# pm-update using linux cron fails

Tags: drush

I use below script to update the drupal - core and modules - using the linux cron.

```
#!/bin/bash
perform_backup(){
cd "$1"
echo "Current working directory : $(pwd)"
if  /usr/bin/drush -r .  status bootstrap | grep -q 'Successful' #Check if a drupal website
then
  if /usr/bin/drush -r . ard --tar-options="--exclude=.git"
  then
    # If archive-dump was successful, then
    # Perform drush update without further backups
    /usr/bin/drush -r . -y pm-update --no-backup
  fi
else
#Do a git commit of the current working directory
git add .
git commit -m"CronBackup-$(date +%s)"
fi
}
export -f perform_backup
find /var/www/html/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'perform_backup "$0"' {} \;
```

The linux `crontab` entry is as follows.

```
0        0          *              *                0,3,6           /usr/bin/drupal-updater >> /var/log/site-update-log
```

and the log details which i got for one website from `/var/log/site-update-log` is like below

```
Current working directory : /var/www/html/example.com
/root/drush-backups/archive-dump/20170304000002/example.20170304_000002.tar.gz
Update information last refreshed: Sat, 2017-03-04 04:52
 Name               Installed  Proposed  Message
                    Version    version
 Metatag (metatag)  7.x-1.20   7.x-1.21  SECURITY UPDATE available
 Panels (panels)    7.x-3.8    7.x-3.9   Update available
 Views (views)      7.x-3.14   7.x-3.15  SECURITY UPDATE available
 Views Slideshow    7.x-3.5    7.x-3.7   Update available
 (views_slideshow)


Security and code updates will be made to the following projects: Metatag [metatag-7.x-1.21], Panels [panels-7.x-3.9], Views [views-7.x-3.15], Views Slideshow [views_slideshow-7.x-3.7]

Note: You have selected to not store backups.
Do you really want to continue with the update process? (y/n): y
Project metatag was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.x-1.21.
Project panels was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.x-3.9.
Project views was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.x-3.15.
Project views_slideshow was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.x-3.7.
```

However, in reality none of those modules were updated though the archive dump of the website was successful. When I did a `pm-update` from the document root, below is the result I got

```
[root@instance-1 example.com]# drush pm-update
Update information last refreshed: Sat, 2017-03-04 09:55
 Name               Installed  Proposed  Message                   
                    Version    version                             
 Metatag (metatag)  7.x-1.20   7.x-1.21  SECURITY UPDATE available 
 Panels (panels)    7.x-3.8    7.x-3.9   Update available          
 Views (views)      7.x-3.14   7.x-3.15  SECURITY UPDATE available 
 Views Slideshow    7.x-3.5    7.x-3.7   Update available          
 (views_slideshow)                                                 


Security and code updates will be made to the following projects: Metatag [metatag-7.x-1.21], Panels [panels-7.x-3.9], Views [views-7.x-3.15], Views Slideshow [views_slideshow-7.x-3.7]

Note: A backup of your project will be stored to backups directory if it is not managed by a supported version control system.
Note: If you have made any modifications to any file that belongs to one of these projects, you will have to migrate those modifications after updating.
Do you really want to continue with the update process? (y/n): n
Aborting.                                                            [cancel]
No database updates required                                         [success]
drush c'all' cache was cleared.                                             [success]
Finished performing updates.                                         [ok]
[root@instance-1 example.com]#
```

The actual updates were made only during manual updation. What is the cause for this?

---

<sup>**Note:** The actual domain name is changed for security reasons</sup>

Comment: I don't have an answer. But what I would try is simplifying the script first. Try to narrow it down. What happens if you create a script, run by cron that only does the upgrade, `/usr/bin/drush -r . -y pm-update --no-backup`. If it works, then keep adding more components. Something to keep in mind. Running from cron, a bash script does *not* have the same environment as running a script from your user session.

Comment: Do you have multiple Drupal sites running on your server? Maybe you just update the wrong one.

Comment: @schlicki : Thankyou but not at all, the log part which I have put in the question is just an excerpt from the log file which contains similar info for other sites as well.. :)

Comment: How about if you changed the script to run `drush -r $1` instead of `drush -r .`, does that make a difference?

Comment: @UltraBob : Well, thought about it and worth a try. But why should it make a difference?

Comment: I don't know that it will, but sometimes I'm surprised by the differences in my expectations about how shell scripts work and how they do in reality. That should remove one more assumption.

Comment: what user is the cron job running the drush command as?  Does that user have the permissions needed to write to the modules directories?

Comment: @UltraBob : The those are root's cronjob. So we can eliminate the possibility that the directories couldn't be written to. :)

Comment: Try to execute script wuth bash -x. This executes the scripts but printing each step and all bash expansions and operations. Sometimes it helps to see a problem that is not obvious reading the code or checking the output. Also make sure you don't any other process reverting changes using git or any other security process.

Comment: Hmm, I will try the debug mode and update you @sanzante